# Create a map in groovy having two collections - with keys and values

Tags: groovy, collections, hashmap

I have two lists:

```
def ids = [1L, 2L, 3L]
def values = [11, 12, 13]
```

I would like to create a `HashMap` with `ids` as keys and `values` as values.

I've tried to use `transpose` but stucked with `GroovyCastException`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`GroovyCollections.transpose(lists)`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/GroovyCollections.html#transpose-java.util.List-) "zips" elements from two lists, e.g.

```
[[1,2], [3,4]].transpose() == [[1,3], [2,4]]
```

You can use it in combination with `.collectEntries()` to create a map from such output:

```
Map map = [ids, values].transpose().collectEntries()
assert map == [1: 11, 2: 12, 3: 13]
```

It will create a map like:

```
[1:11, 2:12, 3:13]
```

using your input data.